# Matplotlib.plot() won't render plots correctly. Makes some sort of web instead

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-science

`plt.plot(x, y)` won't render correctly and will create a mess.
I've tried forcing reinstallation of the matplot library but the problem persists. It is so annoying since I really need to plot datasets for my job but I'm currently unable to.

Here are a couple examples of what I mean..

The lines between points don't make any sense
[image]

Looks like a spider web

[image]

This also happens with time series

Comment: Could you give us more information? Show us what `data_main` is.

Comment: The problem is with your data, not `plot`.  Try plotting a simpler pair of arrays, and then a bit more complex.  Or describe your data more.

Comment: In the first plot, I think you want points, not lines.  That is `scatter`  What's the `x` array?

Comment: As @hpaulj suggests, you can either use `plt.scatter(x, y)` or use `plt.plot(x, y, "o")`.

Comment: If you expect the plot to be something like the graph of a curve, the `x` array must be ordered, either increasing or decreasing.  Apparently your `x` array is not sorted.  See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785997/why-pyplotmatplotlib-is-joining-points-randomly/32786243#32786243