# How can I smooth this jagged numpy polynomial fit line?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to draw a smooth polynomial fit line for a scatter plot, but [it looks like razor wire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcXSo.png)! Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly
import pandas as pd

x = []
y = []
col_names = ['col1','col2','col3']
for sheet in sheets:
    df = pd.read_csv(path, names=col_names)
    x += df['col3'].tolist()
    y += df['col2'].tolist()

plt.scatter(x, y, c='k', alpha=0.2)
coefs = poly.polyfit(x, y, 3)
ffit = poly.polyval(x, coefs)
plt.plot(x, ffit)
plt.show()
```

Setting the degree of fit to 1 draws a clean line, but it's not as helpful as a curved polynomial fit line in this case. The same razor wire texture shows up when I only plot the data from one .csv file instead of appending values from a collection of files.

What likely went wrong to create the jagged line, and what could be done to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scipy.curve\_fit() returns multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516862/scipy-curve-fit-returns-multiple-lines)

Comment: Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785997/why-pyplotmatplotlib-is-joining-points-randomly

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your **x** values are jumbled all over the place.

If you sort these, and apply the same sort to the **y** values you will get a better fit.

```
x = numpy.array(x)
y = numpy.array(y)
order = numpy.argsort(x)
x = x[order]
y = y[order]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mr. T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8881141/mr-t) commented and linked to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516862/scipy-curve-fit-returns-multiple-lines) from someone using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` instead of `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit()`. Based on suggestions there, I made this adjustment:

```
ffit = poly.polyval(sorted(x), coefs)
plt.plot(sorted(x), ffit)
```

Which produced [what I was hoping for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuEUV.png). The problem was that the x values were drawn out of order, creating that zigzag pattern. The order of y values doesn't matter after running `poly.polyfit()`, so sorting the x values whenever they're called after that fixed the issue.